# Send bulk emails from Gmail SMTP with PEAR library by using proxy IPs

Tags: proxy, smtp, gmail, ip, block

We have multiple gmail and yahoo accounts (about 10 each). We use them send emails using Gmail and Yahoo SMTPs. AFter sending certain number of emails a day, both (gmail and yahoo) blocks our email accounts. Not 1 or 2 accounts but all the 10 accounts - together.

We are using PHP PEAR library. I am sure gmail and yahoo has a way to find out our server IP and they block all the emails that are sending request from that IP. Is there a way to use proxy IPs here so that gmail/yahoo do not know the requests are coming from 1 IP?

Comment: are you asking how to avoid spam detection for your spamming needs ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to cheat gmail and yahoo and they wont allow you. they are master in email solution so don't try and illegal method and waste your time.